Serve files from host machine through Spring Boot
I have some pdf files in my host machine where my backend service is deployed that I want to serve publicly. The requirement is to make file updating dynamic such that the client can replace the outdated files with new ones through a module I have created for them. Of course, I could serve the files through an endpoint but that is less efficient because it routes requests through the full application stack, adding processing overhead compared to direct static file serving by the web server.
Following is what I added in application.properties folder:
spring.web.resources.static-locations=file:/home/spidey/sopon3/rda-aof/

This works by accessing my-devdomain.com/public-data.pdf, however, due to spring security, accessing it requires authentication. I tried allowing /rda-aof/** in my security config but it doesn't work and I cannot just allow /** because it will allow all endpoints. So what is the workaround for this? Also, feel free to suggest other methods if this isn't going to work.
I am adding the security config code for reference:
package ca.p6son.spring.config.security;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    @Autowired
    Environment env;
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
/*
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
    // user for matching credentials
    // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
*/
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        //return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11, new SecureRandom());
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        logger.info("AuthManager init: " + super.authenticationManagerBean().toString());
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        boolean isProd = (Arrays.stream(env.getActiveProfiles()).findFirst().orElse(null)).equals("prod");

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/v1/geojson/atm",
                            isProd ? "/api/v1/invalid/path1" : "/swagger-ui/**",
                            isProd ? "/api/v1/invalid/path2" : "/v3/api-docs/**",
                            "/api/v1/account/resend_otp",
                            "/api/v1/resource/**",
                            "/api/v1/geojson/branches",
                            "/api/v1/guides",
                            "/api/v1/faq",
                            "/actuator/**",
                            "/api/v1/products",
                            "/api/v1/version_validate",
                            "/api/v1/security_guides",
                            "/api/v1/biometric_challenge", // To enable
                            "/api/v1/bio-override", 
                            "/api/v1/dao/bio-override", 
                            "/api/v1/push-notification", 
                            "/api/v1/deals_and_offers",
                            "/api/v1/city_list",
                            "/api/v1/users",
                            "/api/v1/cleanup/*",
                            "/api/v1/account/forgot_username/*",
                            "/api/v1/account/forgot_password/*",
                            "/api/v1/auth/**",
                            "/api/v1/validate/pin",
                            "/api/v1/test",
                            "/api/v1/cleanup",
//                            "/api-docs/**",
//                            "/swagger-ui.html",
//                            "/swagger-ui/**",
//                            "/v3/api-docs/**",
                            "/inter-module/**",
                            "/rda-aof/**",
                            "/api/v1/verify-email-link",
                            "/api/v1/robo/**",
                            "/api/v1/terms_and_conditions").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .headers(headers -> {
                    headers.addHeaderWriter((request, response) -> {
                        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
                        if (!(requestURI.startsWith("/api/v1/resource/alerts") || requestURI.startsWith("/api/v1/verify-email-link"))) {
                            // Apply headers to all requests except the excluded endpoint
                            response.addHeader("Referrer-Policy", "strict-origin-when-cross-origin");
//                            response.addHeader("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block");
                            response.addHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; base-uri 'self'; form-action 'self'");
                            response.addHeader("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains");
                            response.addHeader("Permissions-Policy", "geolocation=(self), microphone=(), camera=()");
                        }
                    });
                })
                .cors().and().csrf().disable(); // TODO: Security issue?


        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}


Sure, I have added the config in my question.

I was able to answer my own question after much brainstorming and apparently the solution was very simple. Since /home/spidey/sopon3/rda-aof/ has been configured as the directory to serve the files that can be accessible using just my-devdomain.com/data-file.pdf, all I had to do was create another directory inside /rda-aof and put my files there. So now the url looks like this: my-devdomain.com/public/data-file.pdf. With this, I was able to configure spring security to allow /public/** without any authentication.
